# Have All TD and TR Tags of HTML Table Hidden on Page Load

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, html-table, webforms

I do not want to hide the table itself, just the header and the row tags.  I then want to conditionally show them based on user selection.  Is there a catch-all that will on page load hide all of the td and tr tags for the table?

Or do I need to go through and manually set the visible=false for all of the td and tr tags in the aspx then in my aspx.cs set the Visible=true when I want to show?

Comment: Add a CSS class to the elements and then enable/disable the elements changing the display property of the CSS class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do the following:

- during rendering assign a class like `hideRow` to all TD/TR elements
- add a CSS class to hide such elements, e.g. `.hideRow { display: none; }`
- via JS remove the class if the user selects a row to be shown, e.g. `$('#ID').removeClass('hideRow');`

Comment: I like the idea of using a css class to hide all from the get-go - but is it possible to use C# to show the row and over-ride the css class?

Comment: As you said this should happen client-side: No; C# is server-side, JS is client-side. Except you want that persisted and post-back every change and read out the settings during rendering...

Comment: Ah - good call on that.  I would not want postback on everything.  I will look at how to do such with JS :)

Comment: wouldn't you have a problem with colspan and rowspan by hiding/showing dynamically and selectively? I've never done this before so I'm curious, since it does not sound logical to me that this can be done by just `display:block/none`

Comment: @Ivan86 Yes, if you use colspan/rowspan you would get strange results. I assume the OP does not do that...

Comment: @ChrFin Well, yes I agree, but I was wondering how is it even possible to show a different amount of cols in different rows...In the absence of colspan and rowspan does the table automatically take care of this? I'm not really sure it would work properly

Comment: @ChrFin Oh, I see it seems the OP wants to only hide/unhide rows. In that case this would work perfectly, but if he wants to be able to select and hide certain `<td>` I think he will have to play with colspan also.

Comment: @Ivan86: Again, I assumed the OP will not create "mixed rows/cols" - as long as you only hide complete rows/columns it works fine...

Comment: @ChrFin Yes,  exactly. I thought the OP required selective `<td>` hiding/unhiding as well. If not, this is the answer he is looking for!